# What is the role of temp = 0 in finding primes?

Tags: java, primes

I have the following code to print all prime numbers from `2` to `100`:

```
int number1 = 2, number2 = 100, temp = 0;
System.out.println("prime numbers between" + number1 + "and" + number2 + "are :");

for (int i = number1; i <= number2; i++) {
    for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            temp = 1;
            break;
        } else {
            temp = 0;
        }
    }

    if (temp == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

What is the role of `temp = 0` in the very beginning?

If I modify it to, lets say `1`, I get a different output. The code then prints all primes starting from `5` instead of `2`. Why are the other numbers skipped?

Comment: There is no point in it being an `int`. It's effectively a boolean, and its meaning would be clearer if it were declared as such.

Comment: this is _technically_ irrelevant from the question but this prints out all primes from 2 to num2/2 which in this case is 50

Comment: @TruVortex_07 This might have been just an edit mistake from my side since the original code had `number´´` and I tried to guess-restore it. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: And `for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {` should be `for (int j = 2; j <=Math.sqrt(i); j++) {`

Comment: @Zabuzard no no, you misunderstood me, abhay also has num2/2

Comment: The original code, before I started editing, had `i<=number´´2` and the `´´` are probably just a typo since there is not even a `number` variable, but `number2`. I mistook it for `number / 2` at first.

Comment: @Zabuzard oh, i see, that makes sense

Comment: And temp is not required.  If the number is divisible, then do `continue outer;`  and put the label `outer` on the outer loop. Once you exhaust the inner loop, print the value.  And finally, check divisible by 2 separately.  Then increment the rest by 2 starting with 3.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Have a close look at your loop logic flow:

```
for (int i = number1; i <= number2; i++) { 
    for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            temp = 1;
            break;
        } else {
            temp=0;
        }
    }

    if (temp == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

`i` starts as `2` and increments. The inner loop is:

```
for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
```

---

### Inner loop is skipped

That means that for the first iterations of the outer loop, for example `i = 2` the condition of the inner loop evaluates to:

```
j <= i / 2
// which is
2 <= 2 / 2
// which is
2 <= 1
```

Hence the inner loop does not even enter at all and is skipped. So we directly reach

```
if (temp == 0) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

The same is true for the iterations, `i = 3`.

`i = 4` is the first iteration that actually enters the inner loop and starts overwriting `temp` with either `0` or `1`.

---

### Meaning of `temp == 0`

So during the first iterations of the outer loop (`i = 2`, `i = 3`), the initial state of `temp` plays a role, since it determines whether `i` will be printed or not.

So you need it to start as `0` to have the first values, for which the inner loop is not even entered, included in the output.

---

### Notes

That said, using `temp` in such a way is overly complicated. It would be better if it would be moved to the place where it is actually needed, inside the loop, given a better name and also changed to a `boolean`. All in all, you may simplify the code as follows:

```
int min = 2;
int max = 100;
System.out.println("prime numbers between" + min + "and" + max + "are :");

for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
    for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isPrime) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

And if you are willing to introduce a helper method like:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int candidate) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= candidate / 2; i++) {
        if (candidate % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Your code will heavily simplify and be very easy to read:

```
int min = 2;
int max = 100;
System.out.println("prime numbers between" + min + "and" + max + "are :");

for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand, what is the role of the variable `temp` in this code.

The variable `temp` is behaving like a flag, means whenever the number found to be divisible by another number, `temp` variable is setting as `1` and the code stops checking.

if we scan all the number upto `i/2` and the variable `temp` is still 0, means we didn't find any number `j` which can divide current number `i`, then the current number is prime.

edit:
the role of `temp=0` at the very beginning assumes all the number is prime. if found later number is divisible then we are assigning `temp=1` and we get to know that the number is not prime.

Answer (score 0):

The role in `temp` is to simply indicate if a prime was or was not found. Then use that value to control printing of the value under test.  But it is not really needed (and as already stated in the comments, should have been a `boolean`).

Here is one way you could improve your effort without using that value.

Other than dividing by already found primes, you can make it somewhat more efficient by doing the following:

- If the first prime is even, check to make certain it isn't 2.
- if it is, print it.
- if even, increment `number1` by `1` to make it odd.
- then starting iterating by both candidates and divisors by two to get just the odd numbers.
- don't divide by any number > the square root of the candidate.  Otherwise you are wasting time.  Example, if 97 is not divisible by any of 3,5,7,11 then it must be a prime because any larger divisor would return a quotient < 11 which has already been checked.
- you don't need a `temp` value.  Just continue to the outer loop if the number is divided. Otherwise, print the number.

```
int number1 = 2, number2 = 100;
System.out.println("prime numbers between" + number1 + "and"
        + number2 + "are :");
if (number1 % 2 == 0) {
    if (number1 == 2) {
        System.out.println(2);
    }
    number1++;
}
outer:
for (int i = number1; i <= number2; i += 2) {
   int max = (int)Math.sqrt(i);
   for (int j = 3; j <= max; j += 2) {
      if (i % j == 0) {
        // try next candidate
        continue outer;
      } 
   }
   // must be a prime so print it.
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

A better approach is to use the [Sieve of Erastosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).  A `BitSet` is perfect for this.  The idea is to:

- mark every bit that is not a prime.
- This eliminates composite numbers since it eliminates all their prime factors from the composite positions in the `bitset`.
- The unset bit positions in the bitset are then primes.
- as the list is being built, the first unset (clear) bit in the list is as prime.

```
BitSet bits = new BitSet();
bits.set(0,2); // set bits 0 and 1
```

initialize nextBit to the first prime

```
int nextBit = 2; // essentially bitSet.nextClearBit(0);
```

Continue the loop while the next bit is less than the square root of the terminal value.

```
while (nextBit <= Math.sqrt(number2)) {
    // mark every prime position after this one.
    for (int i = 2*nextBit; i < number2; i += nextBit) {
        bits.set(i);
    }
    // the next clear bit after the previous prime must be a prime 
    // since it is next unset bit
    nextBit = bits.nextClearBit(nextBit+1);
}
```

Now display them

```
// This is done by simply printing all the bit positions
// that are clear up to the terminal value.
int i = bits.nextClearBit(0);
while (i < number2) {
    System.out.println(i);
    i = bits.nextClearBit(i+1);
}
```